# Unwanted cookies in a Flutter & Firebase web app

Tags: flutter, firebase, web, cookies

I am working on GDPR for my flutter web app with Firebase.
I see all theses cookies are set when I login in my app. They are all set by `google.com` and seem to be aimed at ad targeting (according to some websites that use them):

```
___Secure-ENID
___Secure-3PSIDCC
___Secure-3PSID
___Secure-3PAPISID
___Secure-1 PSIDCC
___Secure-1 PSID
___Secure-1 PAPISID
SSID
SIDCC
SID
SAPISID
NID
HSID
APISID
AEC
1P JAR
```

I never wanted this type of behavior in my app. Where can I prevent these from being created?

Note: Since the Firebase Auth login cache is stored in the local / session browser storage, I don't think these cookies are necessary (but maybe I'm wrong).